# How to remove quotes from dictionary value string dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, exasol

I have a dictionary like: `d = {'table': 'db_schema.foo', 'column': 'bar'}`. I want to pass this dictionary after removing quotes from all values. So I want to get `{'table': db_schema.foo, 'column': bar}` dynamically.

Details:

I am trying to pass run a dynamic query into exasol after connecting. I am using pyexasol here and trying [`execute()`](https://github.com/badoo/pyexasol/blob/master/docs/REFERENCE.md#execute) . I am trying to execute simple query like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM db_schema.foo
WHERE bar >= 0
```

If I provide dictionary `d` then the query that's get executed is:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM 'db_schema.foo'
WHERE 'bar' >= 0
```

and results in error. So I want to remove quote from all values.  I have tried `{k:v.strip("\'") for k, v in d.items()}` etc. but not successful yet.

Requested Code:

```
foo_query = '''select *
                from {app_table}
                where {col} >= '2020-01-01'
                limit 10;'''
foo_param={'app_table': 'src.application',
             'col': 'createdat'}
foo_results = exasol.runQueryExaParams(query=foo_query, query_param=foo_param)
foo_results1 = exasol.runQueryExaParams(query=foo_query, query_param={k:v.strip("\'") for k, v in foo_param.items()})
```

where exasol is a class built on pyexasol with just connection parameters. Relevant method from class there is:

```
    def runQueryExaParams(self, query, query_param):
        self.conn = pyexasol.connect(
            dsn=self.__dsn, user=self.__user, password=self.__password, encryption=True)
        res = self.conn.export_to_pandas(query, query_param)
        self.conn.close()
        res.columns = res.columns.str.lower()
        return res
```

In both cases I am getting same error:

```
pyexasol.exceptions.ExaQueryError: 
(
    message     =>  syntax error, unexpected simple_string_literal [line 3, column 22] (Session: )
    dsn         =>  
    user        =>  
    schema      =>  
    code        =>  42000
    session_id  =>  
    query       =>  EXPORT (
select *
                from 'src.application'
                where 'createdat' >= '2020-01-01'
                limit 10
) INTO CSV
AT 'https://1.2.3.4' FILE '000.csv'
WITH COLUMN NAMES
)
```

Comment: The quotes are just part of the representation of the dictionary, they're not actually present in the value. Please show your actual code for the `execute` call.

Comment: Post your code and full error message you are getting. The quotes shown on the dictionary are just the way Python represents strings.

Comment: You need to read [SQL FORMATTING](https://github.com/badoo/pyexasol/blob/master/docs/SQL_FORMATTING.md). Specifically `!i`, _"Validates identifer and puts it without quotes. It allows you to pass lower-cased identifiers to query upper-cased named tables while keeping it "safe". It is the "convenient" version of identifier placeholder."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you need to read [SQL FORMATTING](https://github.com/badoo/pyexasol/blob/master/docs/SQL_FORMATTING.md).

With that said, you need to change your code to be something like this:

```py
query = '''
    SELECT *
    FROM {app_table!q}
    WHERE {col!i} >= '2020-01-01'
    LIMIT 10;
'''

query_param = {
    'app_table': ('src', 'application'),
    'col': 'createdat'
}

results = exasol.runQueryExaParams(
    query=query,
    query_param=query_param
)
```

As the documentation indicates, the code above will result in a query like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "src"."application"
WHERE createdat >= '2020-01-01'
LIMIT 10;
```

I hope it helps.